How to fix error code 137 with Eclipse CDT on docker
I'm using Eclipse on Windows for C++ development. As my software developped is in Linux, I'm using a container for compiling, not debugging yet.
I've configured the setup in february 2024, it was working for a while and about 1 month ago, I starded having errors "make -j4 all" terminated with exit code 137. Build might be incomplete.. When I relaunch the build, eventually it will complete, but most of the times with file format errors or other stuff.
Current setup :

Computer has 16GB of RAM
Windows 11, updated
WSL 2 - Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)
Eclipse 4.31.0
Eclipse CDT 11.5.0.202402
C/C++ Docker Container Launch Support 11.5.0.202312
Docker Desktop 4.30.0

I've tried :

Running make manually direcly in container launched via Windows PowerShell : working fine
Changing RAM limit of Docker Desktop / WSL2 to double : no change
Rebooting computer : no change
Changing Java RAM limits of Eclipse : no change
Reducing to one thread (make -j1 all) : no change


What does exit code 137 mean?

@nitind From my reseach, it would be 137 - 128 -> 9, so signal 9 SIGKILL. Some people are telling it is the OS that kill it for overmemory usage, but this is odd since it is working manually in same container.
